# Unable to set field/property on entity type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two models as below

```
public class np_claim_hdr
    {
        [Key]
        public decimal CLAIM_ID { get; set; }
        ----------
         ---------------
        --------------
     [InverseProperty("header")]
        public virtual IList<np_claim_dtls> np_claim_dtls { get; set; }
}


public class np_claim_dtls
    {
         [Key]

        public decimal CLAIM_ID { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("CLAIM_ID"), InverseProperty("np_claim_dtls")]
        public virtual np_claim_hdr header { get; set; }
        public string PROV_CODE { get; set; }
        public string PROV_DESC { get; set; }
        public string PRIMARY { get; set; }
}
```

When I am setting the object of model `np_claim_hdr` it is giving me error related to the rows of `np_claim_dtls`

I tried as below

```
 np_claim_hdr header = new np_claim_hdr();
 header = db.np_claim_hdr.Find(1500);
```

and it is getting value of `np_claim_hdr` but value of `np_claim_dtls` inside the same is giving error as shown in the screen shot below

[image]

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to set field/property np_claim_dtls on
>   entity type
>   System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.np_claim_hdr_047D7A4CFCF9316F6A7AEE7D891D9077FC5B931247DC389C8EB4D53A2F935577. See InnerException for details.
>
> InnerException: Make sure the source type is convertible to the
>   destination type.
>
> InnerException: When casting from a number, the value must be a number
>   less then infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Posting it answer because it may help others in future.

In both model is used `CLAIM_ID` as `[Key]`  it is not possible because `CLAIM_ID` of primary key in `np_claim_hdr` is using as foreign key in `np_claim_dtls`. So specifing another primary key for the model `np_claims_dtls` solved the issue

```
public class np_claim_hdr
    {
        [Key]
        public decimal CLAIM_ID { get; set; }
        ----------
         ---------------
        --------------
     [InverseProperty("header")]
        public virtual IList<np_claim_dtls> np_claim_dtls { get; set; }
}


public class np_claim_dtls
    {
         [Key]
         public decimal ID { get; set; }

        public decimal CLAIM_ID { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("CLAIM_ID"), InverseProperty("np_claim_dtls")]
        public virtual np_claim_hdr header { get; set; }
        public string PROV_CODE { get; set; }
        public string PROV_DESC { get; set; }
        public string PRIMARY { get; set; }
}
```